# GetStateByPartialCompositeKey by a specific key not working

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Currently I'm working with Hyperledger chaincode, 
I have a problem with the method "GetStateByPartialCompositeKey". 
They index consists of 3 parts (key1~key2~key3). 
If i try GetStateByPartialCompositeKey(index, key1) , it works perfectly. 
But If I try to search for another key, like GetStateByPartialCompositeKey(index, key3), nothing is returned. Although the key is actually saved.  How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer: https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetStateByPartialCompositeKey

As mentioned in the description of the method, "This function returns an iterator which can be used to iterate over all composite keys whose **prefix** matches the given partial composite key."

This method needs to have the prefix i.e. the first half of the composite key to match. Even though the method name may state partial key, it only works with the **prefix of the composite key** and not any part of it.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i know why

Comment: user11413769, i want to know a way to put state so i can get state by a part of key.

Comment: As far as i know, there is no method to achieve that till now. You can communicate in the official forum to know if something would come up in the future release. Or you can change your data model to workaround the methods available.